Add rewrite rule to account for dynamically changed page titles
I have a property website which by default outputs property page urls like this:
https://coh.stuartchapmandesign.co.uk/property/2-4-king-street-london/
I have some php that uses 'post_type_link' to automatically update the urls replacing the last word in this case 'London' with the property postcode which returns it as:
https://coh.stuartchapmandesign.co.uk/property/2-4-king-street-sw1y6ql/
Which is loosely based on the documentation for the plugin it uses here: https://docs.wp-property-hive.com/article/619-creating-seo-friendly-property-details-urls
This works and updates the links and urls throughout the site but the issue is when I visit the page I get a 404 page not found error.
Struggling to see why but obviously something to do with the add rewrite rule.
Any help would be hugely appreciated, thank you
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'customise_property_post_type_link', 10, 4 );
function customise_property_post_type_link( $post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'property' ) {
        // Retrieve the postcode from the post meta
        $meta_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
        $postcode = isset( $meta_data['_address_postcode'][0] ) ? sanitize_title( $meta_data['_address_postcode'][0] ) : '';

        // Ensure a valid postcode is available
        if ( ! empty( $postcode ) ) {
            // Remove hyphens from the postcode
            $postcode = str_replace( '-', '', $postcode );

            // Extract the last segment of the URL (the part after the last "/")
            $post_link = preg_replace_callback(
                '/([^\/]+)\/$/',
                function ( $matches ) use ( $postcode ) {
                    // Replace only the last word in the segment
                    return preg_replace( '/[^-]+$/', $postcode, $matches[1] ) . '/';
                },
                $post_link
            );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrites_init' );
function rewrites_init() {
    // Add rewrite rule for property pages with a postcode
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^property/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=property&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}


What value for the name parameter does it actually pass to the index.php?

@C3roe I imagine it would be 2-4-king-street-sw1y6ql, which is why it 404s.

Is changing the slug when it's saved an option?

@C3roe the issue im having is that because this causes a 404 im not sure how to then debug the name parameter into the page

var_dump($_GET); put at the very start of the script would show you what query string parameters it received. But most likely the situation is as @Caleb suspects - it matches the whole thing, and uses that as slug to look up the post in the database. And 2-4-king-street-sw1y6ql (from your parameter) and 2-4-king-street-london (in your database) simply don't match.

@C3roe Thanks for the reply its hugely appreciated any idea on how to fix this?

If manipulating the slug in the database, so that it actually matches the modified URL, is not an option - then maybe just append the postal code? /property/2-4-king-street-london-sw1y6ql/ - and then you make your rewrite rule only capture the first part, which still matches the slug stored in the database?

Also having looked the name being output is 2-4-king-street
Just to recap the original url would have been 2-4-king-street-london and the new one (which i am now viewing the 404 error page on) is 2-4-king-street-sw1y6ql

Is changing the slug when the property is saved an option?
